# Qual é a diferença entre o HttpRequestContext e HttpRequest? E como converter o HttpRequestContext para HttpRequest?

Tags: asp.net

Qual é a diferença entre o HttpRequestContext e HttpRequest? 
E como converter o HttpRequestContext para HttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, o `HttpRequestContext` é um objeto que está "dentro" do `HttpRequest`.

O `HttpRequest` (`System.Web.HttpRequest`) retorna a requisição atual, onde podemos ler o `QueryString` por exemplo.

O `HttpRequestContext` (`System.Web.Routing.RequestContext`) é a requisição dentro da rota atual, uma rota `MVC` por exemplo. Tanto é que se uma requisição não feita através de uma rota, para um página direto por exemplo, o `HttpRequestContext` é vazio.

Converter um `HttpRequestContext` não deve ser problema, pois ele sempre é uma requisição, logo `HttpRequest` deve estar preenchido com os dados da requisição.
Note que `HttpRequestContext` herda de `RequestContextBase`, que por sua vez herda de `RequestContext`, isso pode ajudar.